# Blender copy the location of an object depending on where the object is currently located

Tags: objects, constraints

I have positioned an object on a ship and now want the location of the object to change accordingly with the ship. When I use "Copy Location", the object is always moved to the reference point of the set target object. But I want the object to stay in the position I positioned it before and to change its position with the ship accordingly to its old position.
So Blender should simply remember the reference point to the selected target object and then move it accordingly.

I would be very happy for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just check the "offset" checkbox, then it should do what you want.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hello Chris, thank you very much for your fast reply! 
Yes you are right. I have to reposition it again after clicking, but then it fits!

Comment: i am happy i could help